# (Java) Explicitly/programmatically closing JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, forceclose

Let's say I have a class which extends JPanel:

```
class StockScreenResultsPanel extends JPanel{
    etc...
}
```

Then I have a handle on that class I have just retrieved it from a parent tab:

```
StockScreenResultsPanel childComponent = (StockScreenResultsPanel)nasdaqTab.getComponent();
```

I'm very sorry if this is really nooby, but I want to explicitly close childComponent (not just hide it but eliminate it from the application), and I can't find any examples.

Can someone show me how to explicitly/programmatically close a child JPanel?

I have already tried the code below and get the error "StockScreenResultsPanel  cannot be converted to window"

```
childComponent.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent( (Window)childComponent , WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Also, if I try:

```
childComponent.dispose()
```

It gives me a "cannot find symbol".

Comment: Have you tried just removing it from the `JTabbedPane`?  Since a `JPanel` is just a component, isn't "closable" like window

Comment: You can't close a panel. Therefore, none of your solutions have worked (a panel is not a window, nor is it disposable, since it's just a [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html). Try [removing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(java.awt.Component)) the tab itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments in response to my question above say, you can't close a panel, you have to use remove instead.